# Express complex relationship between two variables

Tags: python, math, algebra

I need to write a formula to express a relationship between two variables `a` and `b`.

If `a` has value below 30, `b` should be zero.

If `a` has value is between 30 and 90, `b` should increase `a`:`b` by 2:1.

And if `a` value is above 90, `b` should increase by 4:1.

How could I write this?

Comment: When you say "If a has value is between 30 and 90, b should increase a:b by 2:1", do you mean that b increases by 1/2 of the value of a?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use if-elif-else in a function:

```
def my_func(a,b):
    if a < 30:
        b = 0
    elif 30 <= a & a <= 90:
        b += (a-30)/2
    else:
        b += 30+(a-60)/4
    return a,b

# use the function in the following way:
# a,b = num1, num2
# a,b = my_func(a,b)
```